# error en el for

Tags: php, bucle-for

Hola tengo este código se supone que es para encontrar el pivote de la $lista  pero lo que hace es iterar muchas veces un error hasta que cancelo la carga de la pagina alguien sabe en que estoy fallando

```
$lista = array('1', '4', '6', '3', '2');

$sumlight = '0';
$sumright = '0';

for ($i = 0; $i < $lista ; $i++) { 
    for ($j = 0; $j < $i ; $j++) { 
        $sumlight = $lista[$j];
    }
    for ($m = 0; $m < $lista; $m++) { 
        $sumright = $lista[$m];
    }
    if ($sumlight == $sumright && $sumlight != 0 && sumright != 0) {
        print_r($i);
    }
    $sumright = 0;
    $sumlight = 0;
}
```

Comment: Pues así mirando por encima, lo priero que veo es que la condición de salida del bucle está mal, pues $lista es un array, deberías poner count($lista) en su lugar. Documentación de count en http://php.net/manual/es/function.count.php

Comment: <A que te refieres con pivote?

Comment: el numero pivote o indice de esa lista a lo que voy es que el pivote es el índice donde la suma de los números de la izquierda es igual a la suma de los números de la derecha. Dado [1, 4, 6, 3, 2], el método debe devolver 2, ya que la suma de los números a la izquierda del índice 2 es igual a la suma de los números a la derecha del índice 2 (1 + 4 = 3 + 2). Si no existe tal índice, debe devolver -1

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo bien lo que quieres lograr, pero la correccion al codigo a como lo colocaste seria:

1. En el ciclo for el 2do condicional que indica el comparador, debe ser count(), porque de lo contrario no obtendras el numero del array $lista, sino un array de datos.
2. Las variables de la linea 3 y 4 se recomiendan numéricas, pero igual no te afecta tratarlas como ahorita lo haces. Pero aun asi lo dejo como lo tienes originalmente.

> ```
> <?php
> $lista = array('1', '4', '6', '3', '2');
>
> $sumlight = '0';
> $sumright = '0';
>
> for ($i=0; $i<count($lista); $i++) { 
>     for ($j=0; $j<$i; $j++) { 
>         $sumlight = $lista[$j];
>     }
>     for ($m=0; $m<count($lista); $m++) { 
>         $sumright = $lista[$m];
>     }
>     if ($sumlight == $sumright && $sumlight != 0 && sumright != 0) {
>         print_r($i);
>     }
>     $sumright = 0;
>     $sumlight = 0;
> }
> ?>
> ```

Adicionalmente:

echo $lista;

> Resultado: Array...

print_r($lista);

> Resultado: array( [0]=>'1', [1]=>'4', [2]=>'6', [3]=>'3', [4]=>'2' )

echo count($lista);

> Resultado: 5

Comment: no quiero saber cuantos números tiene mi lista si no el numero pivote o indice de esa lista a lo que voy es que el pivote es el índice donde la suma de los números de la izquierda es igual a la suma de los números de la derecha. Dado [1, 4, 6, 3, 2], el método debe devolver 2, ya que la suma de los números a la izquierda del índice 2 es igual a la suma de los números a la derecha del índice 2 (1 + 4 = 3 + 2). Si no existe tal índice, debe devolver -1

Comment: a lo que voy, es que no puedes usar un ciclo for() indicando $lista, debes poner count($lista), sino NO podras recorrer el arreglo.

Comment: El codigo que pusiste ya esta corregido, si no hace lo que quieres es porque estas fallando en el proceso logico.

Comment: ah ok entonces revisare la logica de nuevo, gracias

Comment: si porque mira "$sumlight = $lista[$j];", eso jamas va a sumar, simplemente estas declarando.